# Snowflake sample database tables are retrieved instead of my private database-Django-snowflake package

Tags: django, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, inspectdb

I have specified correct database config variable with all the required credentials of my local database that is hosted,but when I am trying to auto generate models for my tables from inspectdb command,I am receiving only SNOW_FLAKE_SAMPLE schema tables into my models file

I tried using options key which is specified on django-snowflake package description but receiving same tables from snowflake_sample_database schema.

These is a problem of [snowflake-django package](https://pypi.org/project/django-snowflake/) only,because i am able to connect through [snowflake.connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html)

Ps-I have given a read access only and database which is required is only visible on snow flake portal when i am on a worksheet dashboard.

Comment: hi just to confirm it is picking up the configuration details from the file you think it is picking, can you give wrong userid/password and see if it still works and picks up the sample DB.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal got incorrect username and password error.

Comment: it looks like the confiuration file is the correct file, can you run show schema and see if you are able to see the schema that you want.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal I am able to access database when I am using python-snowflake connector,but I am receiving snowflake_sample_dataset when I am using django-snowflake package.